# Konva: Finding node at given position (e.g. mouse pointer). Similar to `getDomElementAt()`

Tags: konvajs

In Konva, is there a function that gives the node(s) at the **a given position**? I guess it should be somewhere, but I didn't find it.

I'm also wondering, for a given node, how we can obtain it's bounding rect. I.e. the equivalent of the DOM function: `getBoundingClientRect()`.

Thanks in advance.
Regards,
Cristian.

Comment: Someone just downvoted the question. I'm wondering why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the answer:

```
const mousePos = this.refs.stage.getPointerPosition();
const e = this.refs.stage.getIntersection(mousePos)
console.log(e.getClientRect({ relativeTo: e.getStage() }));
```